# Catching errors in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have weird problem, when im using try/catch method for some cmdlets its working for some not.

Can you advice on that?

This one is working fine:

```
try
{ 
$LookingForRemoteMailboxOnPrem  = Get-RemoteMailbox $info  -ErrorAction Stop | select -ExpandProperty UserPrincipalName 
}
catch
{
string]$t = $Error[0]
}
```

But this one is not:

```
try
{
$EnableRemoteMailbox = Enable-RemoteMailbox $info -RemoteRoutingAddress $remote -PrimarySmtpAddress $info2 -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch
{
[string]$t = $Error[0]
}
```

Not saving error to $t variable

Comment: What is the error that isn't being handled? Do you get the same behavior if you set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`?

Comment: Try `$t = $_` instead

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers $ErrorActionPreference is set up for Continue

Comment: @a Ok it's working with STop

Comment: Please show the error.

Answer (score 0):

The `$ErrorActionPreference` is set to `Continue` by default. This means if PowerShell can "recover" from an error it won't throw an exception. You can use the `-ErrorAction` parameter to change the behaviour at every cmdlet.

This [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/09/16/understanding-non-terminating-errors-in-powershell/) gives a good example:

`Try {dir c:\missingFolder}
Catch [System.Exception] {"Caught the exception"}
Finally {$error.Clear() ; "errors cleared"}`

The string `"Caught the exception` does not occur in PowerShell windows. If you set the `-ErrorAction` to `Stop` an exception is raised.

Details are described [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/09/16/understanding-non-terminating-errors-in-powershell/).